# Prooving that the transversal intersection of regular surfaces is a regular curve.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, tangent-spaces

On his book on differential geometry, Do Carmo has an excercise on section 2-4, essentially excercise 17.

## Problem

That states:

> Show that the transversal intersection of two regular surfaces $S_1, S_2$ is a regular curve.
> A transversal intersection is one such that $p \in S_1 \cap S_2 \implies T_p(S1) \neq T_p(S_2)$.

## Solution

Slader has one possible [solution:](https://www.slader.com/textbook/9781428833821-studyguide-for-differential-geometry-of-curves-and-surfaces-by-docarmo/68/exercises/17/#) But although I am able to follow the math per se. Something isn't clicking. Moreover the author used a theorem that isn't in the prior sections of the book, and it is quite involved (I understand the result but I have never seen the proof and so this won't help me get the intuition right).

## My work

The way I tried to do it was, the intersection must be a curve a point or the empty set, otherwise if it is a surface the tangent spaces at that point cannot disagree.

Assume the intersection is a curve $C$. $C$ contains $p$ by construction.

Then since $S_1$ is a regular surface $\forall p \in S_1 \exists f: U\subset R^2 \rightarrow V \subset S_1$ Such that $p \in f(U)$ $f$ is differentiable, a homeomorphism, and the rank of the jacobian of any point in $f(U)$ is 2.

Consider $C_p = C \cap V$ A subsection of $C$ that is contained in $V$ and contains $p$.

$\forall p \in C_p; \exists x \in U$ such that $f(x) = p$, since $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Here I get stuck, I want to justify that either $C_p$ is continuous or that $f^{-1}(C_p)$ is continuous. If I get either one of those conditions, I think I can continue since the homeomorphism condition implies the other must also be continuous and then:

Since $f^{-1}(C_p) = I$ is continuous then since $f$ is differentiable we get that $f'(x_p) = v \in T_p(S_1)$ where $x_p \in I$.

An analogous argument on $S_2$ will give us $w \in T_p(S_2)$.

And then I want to show that it is not possible for both of these vectors to be 0 simultaneously (somehow) which implies the curve is regular since it has a non zero tangent vector everywhere.

Comment: You don't know the implicit function theorem or the inverse function theorem? If you don't know any of them it will be hard to use the transversal intersection condition.

Comment: Well now I know them, but the point is that neither are in teh precluding chapters in Do Carmo

Comment: In the preface of the book it is written, "From calculus, a certain
familiarity with calculus of several variables (including the statement of the implicit function theorem) is expected." I think you should use it. Otherwise you have to invent it to solve the problem.