# Intersection of regular surfaces is a regular curve

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to prove that if $S_1$ and $S_2$ are regular surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then $S_1\cap S_2$ is a regular curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$. 
Specifically, I want to solve the problem 17.b. of section 2.2 in Do Carmo's book on differential geometry, which states

> **17** Define a regular curve in analogy with a regular surface. Prove that
>
> a. The inverse image of a regular value of a differentiable
> function$$f:U\subset \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$$is a regular plane
> curve. Give an example of such a curve which is not connected.
>
> b. The inverse image of a regular value of a differentiable
> map$$F:U\subset \mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^2$$is a regular curve in
> $\mathbb{R}^3$. Show the relationship between this proposition and the
> classical way of defining a curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as the
> intersection of two surfaces.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3925741/prooving-that-the-transversal-intersection-of-regular-surfaces-is-a-regular-curv) gives a link with [solutions](https://www.slader.com/textbook/9781428833821-studyguide-for-differential-geometry-of-curves-and-surfaces-by-docarmo/68/exercises/17/#) of the problem. I can follow the proof until the point where it says

> Specially, $\nabla f_1(p)\neq 0$ and $\nabla f_2(p)\neq 0$, which implies that the surfaces $f_1^{-1}(c_1)$ and $f_2^{-1}(c_2)$ are regular.

I understand why the surfaces are regular, but I don't know why this implies that $f_1^{-1}(c_1)\cap f_2^{-1}(c_2)$ is a regular curve. 
 
Edit: 
Apparently the key fact is that gradients are linearly independent, but I still can't see why if this happens then the intersection becomes a regular curve.

Comment: The intersection of regular surfaces is not necessarily a regular curve. A fairly trivial example is when $f_1(x,y,z)=f_2(x,y,z)=z$, so $f_1^{-1}(0)=f_2^{-1}(0)=\{z=0\}$ (both surfaces are the $xy$-plane). A better example is $f_1(x,y,z)=z$, $f_2(x,y,z)=z-xy$, so $f_1^{-1}(0) \cap f_2^{-1}(0)$ is the union of the $x$ and $y$ axes (in the $xy$-plane), defined by the equations $z=xy=0$. The surfaces $\{z=0\}$ and $\{z-xy=0\}$ are regular, in particular at the origin–the gradients are both $(0,0,1)$. And this points to the problem. The gradients (normal vectors) have to be independent.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the question. Do you know how do we get the result when gradients are LI?

Comment: The _implicit function theorem_ is the missing ingredient. You might also do a web search for _transversality_.